# Remove rows where a column contains a specific substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how to eliminate rown that have a word i don't want?
I have this DataFrame:

```
index  price    description
0      15       Kit 10 Esponjas Para Cartuchos Jato De Tinta ...
1      15       Snap Fill Para Cartuchos Hp 60 61 122 901 21 ...
2      16       Clips Para Cartuchos Hp 21 22 60 74 75 92 93 ...
```

I'm trying to remove the rown with the word 'esponja'

i want a DataFrame like this:

```
index  price    description
    1      15       Snap Fill Para Cartuchos Hp 60 61 122 901 21 ...
    2      16       Clips Para Cartuchos Hp 21 22 60 74 75 92 93 ...
```

i'm newbe, i don't have any idea how to resolve that

Answer (score 3):

Create a boolean mask by checking for strings that contain `'Esponjas'`, then index into your dataframe with the negated mask.

```
df[~df['description'].str.contains('Esponjas')]
```

If you are unsure what's going on, print out what

```
df['description']
df['description'].str.contains('Esponjas')
~df['description'].str.contains('Esponjas')
```

do on their own. If you want to perform the substring-check case-insensitively, use `case=False` as a keyword argument to `str.contains`.

Comment: i would add `case=False` to ignore the case

Comment: @Datanovice thanks, good suggestion.

Comment: thank you very much for your attention